# Print Composer QGIS 2.6, how to export image?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, jpg

When I finish map in print composer and click on Export to an image format and after I go to folder where I saved it there is no image.
If do same with Export as PDF ,I get PDF file but can't open it and it says that file is 0 Mb in size and every time I do export I lose all stuff in composer so I have to do all over again. Is this error in QGIS or something else?

How do I get JPEG image file from my map out of the composer?

Comment: How big is the image you are trying to export (both pixels and page size) and what is the graphics capability of your computer?

Comment: Export resolution is set to 300 dpi and A4 page i didnt try to change it. Im working on AMD Athlon II X2 220 2.8 GHz, 3GB ram, NVIDIA GeForce 7025

Comment: OK - that should not pose any problems.  I don't know why it isn't letting you export a PDF but here's two things to try (click save before you export): 1) In the Composition tab, check 'Print as raster' and try exporting to PDF again (sometimes if you have too many vector layers it gets upset and printing to raster saves memory).  2) To get a JPEG, go Compsoer->Export as image.